# req.busboy.on('file') not firing

Tags: node.js, express, busboy

I have the following form:

```
form(method='post', action='/encoder_post', enctype='multipart/form-data')
    .form-group
        label(for='name') Name
        input.form-control(type='text', id='name', name='name')
    .form-group
        label(for='message') Message
        input.form-control(type='text', id='message', name='message')
    .form-group
        label(for='file') Audio File (*.wav)
        input.form-control(type='file', id='file')
    button.btn.btn-cicada.btn-block(type='submit') Submit
```

Inside `encoder_post`, I have the following function to handle the post request:

```
router.post('/', function(req, res){
    req.busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
        console.log("this is in file");
    });
    req.busboy.on('field', function(key, value, keyTruncated, valueTruncated) {
        console.log("The value is: " + value);
    });
    req.pipe(req.busboy);
});
```

However, whenever I submit the form, the 'field' handler triggers, but the 'file' doesn't.

Inside `app.js` I have:

```
var busboy = require('connect-busboy');
app.use(busboy());
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure `busboy` waits for your handler middle-ware to be reached to fire its parsing events ? I think those events should be handled right when `busboy` starts parsing request.

Comment: @S.D. By default the `connect-busboy` merely setups up an instance on `req.busboy`. It doesn't start parsing until you start writing to it.

Comment: @mscdex Ah yes. You need to pipe request data to it.

Comment: @S.D. Yep, he's already doing that. The problem though is a missing name attribute for the file field.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your file field is missing a `name` attribute.

Comment: Just saved me about a weeks worth of debugging - thank you

Comment: Still struggling even after adding this attribute, wondering if it's because the app's in Angular and I might be missing something else?